# Wordpress qtranslate widget won’t remove

Tags: wordpress, qtranslate, qtranslate-x

I’m using a custom theme in Wordpress and used qtranslate for the multi language part. I activated an SSL certicate and redirected http pages to HTTPS. At that point the menu links lost their slug at the end. After founding out that qtranslate hasn’t been used for a long time I changed to qtranslate-x and followed the migration tips. 
All works now and I have added the language switcher in the menu at the bottom of my page. 
However, the original qtranslate widget at the top is still showing, even after I removed the widget. I can’t remember if I ever hardcoded the switcher in the header, but I can’t seem to find where it is located, so that I can remove it. Help!
The url is thaiprotect.com

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it already. Qtranslate-x changes all old qtrans strings to qtranx, so I couldn’t find it. But there was a call from my theme’s functions.php straight into the header.